# Retrieving data from a List<T> and putting it in a dropdown list using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have retrieved data from the database and put it in a List. I need to access this list of items using Jquery and put them in a dropdown list. Here is my code in the Controller

```
//filling list with data from data reader
List<Object> list=new List<Object>();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    var var1 = (int)read["dbColumn"];
                    var var2 = (string)read["dbColumn2"];
                    list.Add(var1);
                    list.Add(var2);
                }



            var serializer=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string theData = serializer.Serialize(list);
           return theData;
```

In my jquery I have this

```
if (!$.isEmptyObject(data))
        {
            var html = "";
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var first = [data[i].dbColumn];
                var second = [data[i].dbColumn2];

                html += '<option value=' + first + '>' + second + '</option>';
            }
            $('#SelectBox').html("<option>"+html+"</option>").show();
        }
```

Then I have this as the Html code where I want the list to be displayed

```
<select id="SelectBox"></select>
```

When I try this, I get a looooooong list of empty option fields. What could be the issue

Comment: please give a dump of `theData` and provide a working fiddle of the html-part ... I suspect that accessing `.dbColumn`/`.dbColumn2` on your client-side does not work, as serializing at server-side gives a different output

Comment: sorry that should have been dbColumn not dbColumn1... so you're suggesting i serialize on client side

Comment: the only chance to overcome the boundaries is serialization. I suspect that the serialized format is not accessed properly, either by "wrong" (in lexical manner) serialization or wrong access. to validate this a dump of `theData` would be helpful (to check if the accessed properties are really available)

Comment: for(var i = 0; i<len;i = i + 2) { var first = data[i]; var second = data[i+1]}

Comment: Ok. When I alert the data I get the data returned from the controller but i don't believe it is well formed

Comment: html += '<option value="' + first + '">' + second + '</option>';

Comment: rather than j-Query, should you not e using the MVC design and be sending it to your controller as an ActionMethod that returns the list where @Value= MyMethodCall()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just returning a serialized `List<Object>` so there isn't a `dbColumn1` or `dbColumn2` in your result.

It might be worth creating a wrapper class or using a `Dictionary<int, string>` for your results but to make it work using your current code you can change your jQuery code to:

```
var html = "";
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var first = [data[i]];
    var second = [data[++i]];

    html += '<option value=' + first + '>' + second + '</option>';
}
$('#SelectBox').html(html).show();
```

Note that for the `second` value we are just incrementing `i` to get to the next item in the list. We are also just using the value from `data[i]` directly rather than trying to access any properties from it as it is just an array of items.

This gives a select box populated something like this:

[image]

**Edit**
It would seem from the comments that the Json being returned is not being parsed correctly as well as having your indexing and naming incorrect as per the above. Assuming you are using the `jquery.ajax()` method to retrieve the Json it is probably treating the returned item as a string. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the `dataType` parameter (emphasis mine):

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and *anything else will be returned as a string*).

You could change your call to pass `dataType: 'json'` and as per the documentation jQuery will automatically parse it into a JavaScript object:

```
ajaxReq = $.ajax({
    url: '/home/something',
    dataType: 'json', //get jQuery to parse the response for us
    success: function (data) {
        //data is now a parsed JS object
        var html = "";
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var first = [data[i]];
            var second = [data[++i]];

            html += '<option value=' + first + '>' + second + '</option>';
        }
        $('#SelectBox').html(html).show();
    }
});
```

If you want to parse the json manually or you are using a different method to retrieve the results you could parse the json yourself by adding

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

before the line `var len = data.length;`

Comment: I think its i = i + 2 in loop

Comment: @brykneval - I should have incremented i _before_ I used it for `second. I've updated it to be `++i` rather than `i++`.

Comment: I still get the empty list when I use this option.... Could you give an example for the `Dictionary<int, string>`

Comment: @WairimuMurigi are you sure you've copied the code correctly? What do you get if you `alert(data)` and `alert(data[i])`?

Comment: When i alert `data[i]` i get `undefined` and when i alert `data` i get `[dbColumn, "dbCOlumn2",dbColumn, "dbCOlumn2"...]` and so forth

Comment: @WairimuMurigi OK, how do you populate `data`? Have you parsed the json? (something like `data = JSON.parse(data);`)?

Comment: @petelids I also alerted html and i got `<option value=""></option>` seems the data is not being extracted from `data` properly

Comment: No i havent parsed. I serialized at the controller then passed the result to jquery. See in the original question

Comment: @WairimuMurigi your original question doesn't show how you've populated `data` using jQuery. Can you either update the question to show that or try adding the parse code from my comment above (before the `var len = ...` line?

Comment: In jquery? I though serializing was enough. Thanks..... is that the correct syntax for parsing?....

Comment: @WairimuMurigi Yes, that syntax will work. It's a javascript function for parsing json.

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap content of select control in `<option>`.

```
$('#SelectBox').html(html).show();
```

Comment: Good one! i was about write you, no need of `<select>` tags as well, because that is already there with `#SelectBox` object.

Comment: Doesn't work with select either. I am not sure about the syntax in that line actually. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

```
var batch= document.getElementById('id');    
$(batch).append($("<option></option>").val(first ).html(second ));
```

Note `:Id` get using `browser.ie(insepect element)`.

Comment: ?? what is this ?? where is `batch` coming from? where is `id` coming from?